# Do we have any db migration plugin for gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am converting a maven project to gradle. In maven they have used the c5-db-migration plugin. Do we have anything like that in gradle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Flyway Ant Tasks](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/AntTasks).
Also there is a gradle plugin in work (beta status).

Example:

```
configurations {
    flyway
}

task flywayMigrate(dependsOn: "build") << {
    ext.flyway_classpath = files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir) + files(configurations.flyway)
    ant.taskdef(name: 'flywayMigrate', classname: 'com.googlecode.flyway.ant.MigrateTask', classpath: ext.flyway_classpath.asPath)
    ant.flywayMigrate(driver: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', url: 'myurl', user: 'myusername', password: 'mypassword',
            encoding: 'Cp1252', baseDir: 'sql')
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-core:1.7"
    compile "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
    flyway "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0"
    flyway "com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-ant:1.7"
}
```

Comment: When I tried it, this was the error I got "taskdef class com.googlecode.flyway.ant.MigrateTask cannot be found
   using the classloader AntClassLoader[]" Can you please help me?

Comment: How do you invoke the task flywayMigrate?

Answer (score 1):

I have written one which you can find @ (https://github.com/katta/gradle-flyway-plugin)

Simplest usage looks like this

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url uri('http://katta.github.com/repository')
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.katta.gradle.api.plugins:flyway:1.3'
    classpath 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'flyway'

## replace properties with the values with your database settings
flyway {
    driver='org.postgresql.Driver'
    url='jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/flyway' 
    user='postgres'
    password='s#cRet'
}
```

The documentation [here](https://github.com/katta/gradle-flyway-plugin) explains how to use it in detail. Let me know if you face any issues using it.

Comment: where should I put the sql files?

Answer (score 0):

There is a liquibase plugin for gradle available written by tim berglund. The plugin is available at github: https://github.com/tlberglund/gradle-liquibase-plugin

Maybe that helps you.

cheers,
René